# Several large images needed for animation causing memory error

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-animation

I have created a frame animation comprised of 12 images in an XML file. Do I need to scale each image before adding to the animation, to avoid the Out of Memory error? If I make the images smaller, I do not get the out of error. How can I scale the images to build the animation or is that necessary? I also tried to set scaling in the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

//Firstly add Scale Bitmap code and after that use animation.

photoBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(photoBitmap);
// Animation code

Comment: Thanks for your help. I sized each image and added it to the animation. I used BitmapFactory and GetWindowManager() instead of setImageBitmap. I needed to get the dimensions of my window, so I could determine the size of the image.